# how to support my existing django app with new linkedin api changes?

Tags: python, django, linkedin-api

I have used the LinkedIn oauth2 in my application, that used this api

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections
```

But the new api changes do not allow me to get the details of a person.

I am getting this error

```
HTTPError at /complete/linkedin-oauth2/
403 Client Error: Forbidden
```

Comment: Have you checked the docs? 
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields

Comment: yes.but they said have to join partner program in linkedin for        https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections  access.is it free?

Answer (score 0):

**Starting from [May 12, 2015](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition), Linkedin has limited the open APIs. 
Access to `Connections` requires that you apply for and are granted access to this information from LinkedIn.**

You will have to apply to become a member of a relevant Partner Program. Linkedin team will review your application and will reply back within 15 business days.

**Eligibilty Criteria for Linkedin Parner Program:**

(Taken from this [linkedin page.](https://developer.linkedin.com/legal/api-terms-of-use))

You can use their APIs if:

1. You are developing an Application designed to help LinkedIn members be more productive and successful across the web; for example, by augmenting their profile and professional brand in an Application for publishing, discussing and sharing content with like-minded professionals.
2. Your Application is NOT expected to: have more than 250,000 lifetime members; make more than 500,000 daily calls to an API; make more than 500,000 lifetime people search calls to an API; or serve greater than 1 million daily plugin impressions.
3. Your Application DOES NOT rely on access to the APIs as a fundamental aspect of your business.
4. Your Application WILL NOT store or export any data from LinkedIn other than the LinkedIn Profile Data for the LinkedIn member that requested the data.  “Profile Data” means the name, photo, headline, contact information, experience, education, summary, and location of a LinkedIn member. Profile Data excludes connections, network updates, job listings, groups, companies, and any other content.
5. Your Application DOES NOT target current or potential paying customers of LinkedIn products or people engaging in activities related to those products—in other words, Applications used for hiring, marketing, or selling. Here are some examples (and exceptions) of what we mean by hiring, marketing and selling:

**Hiring:** Applications to find a job or fill a job, such as ones used to advertise, post, apply for, search for, recommend, refer, suggest, enhance listings for, or fill permanent jobs, contract positions, or volunteer opportunities, or for anything with a similar functionality (you can, however, use the APIs to develop an Application to let people apply for a job on your company’s career site, as long as it abides by the specification set forth here).

**Marketing:** Applications used by marketers or their customers for marketing campaigns, lead generation, campaign analysis, or for anything with similar functionality (you can, however, use the APIs to develop an Application to let companies manage their social media presence on LinkedIn, as long as it abides by Section 4.5(“Social Media Management: Company Profile and Statistics Data”)).

**Selling:** Applications used by sales or other outbound professionals for generating or finding prospects or leads, for sales intelligence or training, for relationship management, for systematic matching of individuals with their LinkedIn profiles, or for anything with similar functionality.

If you are looking for the Partnership Program application form, you can check this [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply/).

Hope it helps!